# How to only print or get the second result

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, line

I only want to get the second result, which `num` prints and use it.

`savee1` is a .txt file

```
def copycoordinates():


savee1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/USERS/" + username + "/documents/Euro Truck Simulator 2/profiles", title="Choose FIRST File", filetypes=[("sii files", "*.sii")])

savee2 = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/USERS/" + username + "/documents/Euro Truck Simulator 2/profiles", title="Choose SECOND File", filetypes=[("sii files", "*.sii")])

i1 = Label(frame5, text="Chosen FIRST File \n" + savee1)
i1.pack()

i2 = Label(frame5, text="Chosen SECOND File \n" + savee2)
i2.pack()

command=lambda:[save1()]
subprocess.Popen(["C:/SII_Decrypt.exe", savee1])

command=lambda:[save2()]
subprocess.Popen(["C:/SII_Decrypt.exe", savee2])

#time.sleep(1)

with open(savee1, "r+") as save1:

    for num, line in enumerate(save1, 1):
        if "truck_placement:" in line:
            print(num)
```

Comment: Can you give more context or code to this, and more details of the expected output? Or maybe put the content of savee1 here?

Comment: Ok, idk if it was a typing error when you made the question but there are some missing indentations in the for line, if line and the print line.

Comment: Read then edit according to https://StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to bring your Q up to guidelines for Q's that SO is designed to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want the second match, you can try:

```
with open(savee1, "r+") as save1:

match = 0
for num, line in enumerate(save1, 1):
    if 'truck_placement:' in line:
        match += 1
        if match == 2
            print(num)
        else:
            continue
```

The num will print on the second match.

There are definitely better ways, but this is one of the most easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
results = list()
with open(savee1, "r+") as save1:

for num, line in enumerate(save1, 1):
    if "truck_placement:" in line:
        print(num)
        results.append(num)
print(results[1]) #this is the value you want
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations & give an indication of what limitations & assumptions apply. If the Q has already been answered, report the post as a duplicate or write the link in the comments instead of re-answering to keep SO function as designed, ato upholds quality of SO.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what's in your text file, but usually things are separated in some way (line break, tab separated, comma separated). You should split on what ever it is that separates and then you can just index the resulting list. the following code assumes the things you want are separated by new lines:

```
with open(save1, "r+") as infile:
    f=infile.read()

list_o_txt = f.split('\n')
print (list_o_txt[1])
```

if you want to make a sublist of texts that only contain a phrase 'truck_placement'

```
with open(save1,'r') as infile:
    f=infile.read()

list_o_txt = f.split('\n') # produces a list
filtered_list = [line for line in list_o_txt if 'truck_placement' in line] #filters the list
print (filtered_list[1]) #prints the second item
```

Comment: When I do it like this, it gives me this error       Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1337\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\1337\Desktop\python\11.08.2020 16;44.py", line 118, in copycoordinates
    print (filtered_list[1]) #prints the second item
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Ok - so tkinter is a wrinkle you may have added ;) - the problem I think is that I don't know how your txt file is organised - what are you splitting the file on and what should you split the file on. the above code assumes a new line - how is your txt file organised?